# how to isolate one of the two classes

Tags: jquery

i have a link

```
<a href="" class="states state1">More Info</a>
```

and I want to get the class state1 and not states

I have tried this

```
$(".states").attr("class")

"states state1"
```

but when i try

```
>> $(".states").attr("class").not(".states")
TypeError: $(".states").attr("class").not is not a function
>>> $(".states").attr("class").not("states")
TypeError: $(".states").attr("class").not is not a function
```

any ideas how to get the other class

Comment: the problem is i dont have that available

Comment: I only have states available on many different links and each have another class

Comment: I will have four links that that look like this <a href="" class="states state1">More Info</a>
<a href="" class="states state2">More Info</a><a href="" class="states state3">More Info</a><a href="" class="states state4">More Info</a> and i need the other classname to figure out the selected state

Comment: @Tamer, why dont u use ID to store the state?

Comment: @Tamer, you'd be better off storing that in another `data-*` attribute then. <a href="" class="states" data-stateId="state1">more info</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.trim( $(".states").attr("class").replace("states", "") );
```

Will give you the other class.

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/L2AVd/1/**

Answer (score 2):

why dont u just select all that have `.state1`?

```
$('.state1').(js fn...)
```

or if every state (state1, 2, 3, ...) is unique, you can use ID's and get the id easily:

```
$('.state').each(function(){
    var stats_is = this.id;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit brute-forc-ey, but this works:

```
var classes = $('.states').attr('class').replace('states','').trim(' ').split(' ')
for(var i=0;i<classes.length;i++)
    alert(classes[i])
```

Edit: Just to re-itterate what ive already put in a comment, it sounds like you're shoe-horning everything into the class attribute, where you could easily be using another attribute and making your life alot simpler:

`<a href="" class="states" data-stateId="state1">More Info</a>`

now you could just go

```
$('.states').attr('data-stateId')
```

Answer (score 1):

$(".states").toggleClass('states').attr("class")

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZtHnF/)